# Bash 'source': syntax error near unexpected token `then'

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "abcd" ]; then
    echo "a non-empty string"
else
    echo "an empty string"
fi
```

The script runs fine:

```
$ bash test.sh
non-empty string
```

But when I try to *source* it, a strange error message is produced:

```
$ source test.sh
bash: ./test.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
bash: ./test.sh: line 3: `if [ -n "abcd" ]; then
```

Any advice welcome. The problem appears with any script containing the `if` command, including Fedora's `/etc/bashrc` and my other scripts.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: it runs fine for me: `GNU bash, version 4.2.53(1)-release (i586-suse-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Is your current shell bash? `echo $SHELL`

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan: your `type -` solved it. Thank you very much. What I happened is: I made an alias `alias f=find . -name`. Now watch the idiot at work: I wanted an alias for `find . -iname` as well. Guess what name I picked? For a few days, I was using it and didn't realize that 'if' is a keyword...

Comment: Actually, I couldn't make my mind between suggesting you to turn your comment into a proper answer and deleting the whole question so as nobody could see my blunder. ;-) Thank you again, this `type` command is a very useful thing.

Comment: @peter.slizik You're not the first – and you won’t be the last – to do this. I figure it’s worth keeping. Mentioning that you didn’t have the problem when running it non-interactively was a good clue. Actually, now that I think of it, your question is a perfect example of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and deserves an upvote!

Comment: Another reason to use functions (without the keyword `function`) instead of aliases. `if () { find . -name "$@"; }` would have failed immediately.

Comment: @chepner: Why does the `function` keyword make a difference?

Comment: Oddly, `function if () { ... ;}` works. You can only call it indirectly, though; for example, `funcname=if; $funcname`. `if () { ...; }` fails due to the empty subshell command following reserved word `if`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such an error would occur if a command includes the `then` shell keyword without a corresponding `if` keyword.

If the word `if` was used to define an alias, the alias would be expanded before Bash parses your commands, resulting in such an error. This can be checked by running `type -a if`.  If it has been aliased, you’ll see output similar to

```
if is aliased to <some command>
if is a shell keyword
```

The problem can then be resolved by running `unalias if` to remove the alias.

When running `bash test.sh`, the new shell is non-interactive and by default, Bash only expands aliases for interactive shells. Running `source test.sh` means the commands in the file were interpreted in your current (interactive) shell and the problematic alias was expanded.

For future reference, if there are problems in an interactive shell, but not in non-interactive shells, it’s worth running `alias` to check which aliases have been defined.